# Clipboard utility to paste back multiple lines one by one

Tags: x11, clipboard

I need a tool or utility that can take a text file and copy each line onto the clipboard in a way so I can paste back the text line by line by continuously pressing Ctlr-V.

For example, if the text holds these lines

```
line 1
line 2
line 3
```

Then I will get:

```
Ctlr-v: line 1
Ctlr-v: line 2
Ctlr-v: line 3
```

I need it for pasting lines into the terminal when debugging telnet sessions. It is very tedious to copy and paste the lines one by one.

Does such a tool exists, or can it be created using xclip or similar?

It is for Debian based distros if that makes any difference.

Note:
See don_chrissti's comment for a variation to the accepted solution that worked for me.

**Addition:**

This is the script I ended up with. Note the use of double backslash to retain the newlines from the text file.

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf %s\\n "$line" |
  xclip -l 1 -quiet -selection primary
done < telnet
```

It works very well for testing smtp connections over telnet which is my use of it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `xclip`:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
  printf %s "$line" |
    xclip -l 1 -quiet -selection clipboard -in
done < file.txt
```

Replace `%s` with `%s\n` if you need the newline included.

With `-l 1` xclip holds the `CLIPBOARD` selection for one request (by other applications doing <kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd> for instance), and then exits. You need `-quiet`  for `xclip` to do that in foreground.

That won't work if you have an application like `xclipboard` running. Those applications try to always be the owner of the `CLIPBOARD` selection, so will steal it continuously from `xclip`.

If you have such an application running, you can either suspend or kill it, or you could use the `PRIMARY` selection instead (`-selection primary`, or omit `-selection` as `primary` is the default) and paste using the middle mouse button. Many terminal emulators can paste the `PRIMARY` selection upon <kbd>Shift-Insert</kbd>, some other upon <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-Insert</kbd>.

If you want to know who is stealing the CLIPBOARD selection from `xclip`, this may work:

```
xwininfo -id "$(xclip -selection clipboard -o -t CLIENT_WINDOW | od -vAn -tu8)" -wm
```

provided that application offers the CLIENT_WINDOW target (run `xclip -selection clipboard -o -t TARGETS` to see if it does).

See also `expect` (and `dejagnu` for a testing framework based on `expect`) and GNU `screen` to automate inserting text into terminal applications.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. When I run the script, all I get is this output:

Waiting for one selection request. Waiting for a selection request.Waiting for one selection request.

And the clipboard is empty afterwards.

Comment: @mariar, The idea is that `xclip` holds the selection for 1 request with the current line and once it has been queried, do the same with the next line. Normally, when you press CTRL-V in another application, that application should query the selection. Maybe you have some application like `xclipboard` that continuously queries the selection if it's not its owner. You could try using another selection like the primary selection (middle-click to paste) or suspend `xclipboard` or whichever application steal the selection.

Comment: @mariar, I can confirm that `xclip` with the PRIMARY selection works when `xclipboard` is running.

Comment: This didn't work for me either. It just blows through the loop saying "Waiting for one selection request.".

Comment: @slm, with or without the "-selection clipboard"?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - it blows through it in both instances. I'm going to guess that because I'm running Parcellite, that that's the issue? If I disable Parcellite only the "-selection clipboard" blows through.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: it simply loops through the lines and immediately emits "Waiting for one selection request" a multitude of times. It's over before I can even try pasting something. xclipboard doesn't seem to be running, at least I can't see it in the process list. How do I suspend it?

Comment: @slm, If you configured it to use the PRIMARY selection, yes. That's not the default though, and I would find it annoying that an application steals the primary selection like that.

Comment: @marlar, I've added a command to help figure out who steals the selection from `xclip`. Try with both primary and clipboard selection.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - yes it does take PRIMARY. Actually it's very useful it provides a history among other things that I'd be unwilling to give up. Nice to be able to go back through ~25 items and select one that I want to paste. What should be the output from the `xwininfo` command success/failure?

Comment: @StephaneChazelas: `xwininfo` didn't show anything. However, don_chrissti's variation worked (using primary). I appreciate your help very much and I have of course accepted your solution as an answer.